# Irrelevant Search query output in Apache Solr and Cassandra

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax

I am working on Apache Cassandra in which I configured Apache Solr for partial search. 
I am running 2 queries and getting different result.

```
select id from emp where solr_query = 'number:9';
```

This query gives me 0 result.

In another query `select id from emp where solr_query = 'number:9*';`

This query gives me correct result.

Note :-  All records in "number" column have first digit as 9.

Please let me know the possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the correct result. A search for : returns the exact match result. If you had an item where the number was 9, you'd get that as a result.

Your second query is a wildcard that says give me all numbers that begin with 9. That is the one you want to use. Another example would be to use number:*9* - this returns all results that contain a digit 9.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. another issue is , I am only able to get 10 rows per query.. Please check below link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40127050/getting-only-10-rows-in-solr-cassandra-search

Comment: I looked into it - posted an answer - please approve if it makes sense to manage rows from the query.

Comment: I checked your reply.. Thanks for that.. But issue is, I am using Cqlsh for runnig the query. So how I can use this row and start in cqlsh side.. Please help me. I commented there too.. Please have a look.

Comment: Right now I am using LIMIT with Cql Solr query which gives me desired output, but I think DATA read is not that fast .It is taking some instance of seconds to get data,.

Comment: one more issue I am able to check now.. that if I am trying to search like this.. solr_query = 'num1:*1* OR num2:*1*'; It gives me records.. but If I am trying same syntax on text like chinese character, it is not working for me.. solr_query = 'col1:*金泽* OR col2:*金泽*'; this gives me 0 records....

Comment: What does the web-admin interface query return for the second search?