# Getting only 10 rows in Solr Cassandra search

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax

I am working on Datastax Cassandra with Apache Solr for multiple partial search. 
Issue is, everytime I am getting only 10 rows even once I am doing count(*) query, I am able to check there are 1300 rows belong to particular query.

```
nandan@cqlsh:testo> select id from empo where solr_query = 'isd:9*';

 id
--------------------------------------
 5ee5fca6-6f48-11e6-8b77-86f30ca893d3
 27e3e3bc-6f48-11e6-8b77-86f30ca893d3
 f3156e76-6f47-11e6-8b77-86f30ca893d3
 f315ac74-6f47-11e6-8b77-86f30ca893d3
 f315bc82-6f47-11e6-8b77-86f30ca893d3
 27e3058c-6f48-11e6-8b77-86f30ca893d3
 4016eee4-6f47-11e6-8b77-86f30ca893d3
 1bd33e34-6f47-11e6-8b77-86f30ca893d3
 8f0a9168-6f47-11e6-8b77-86f30ca893d3
 6669cc42-6f47-11e6-8b77-86f30ca893d3

(10 rows)
```

After searching few links, I make changes into solrconfig.xml file. and changes are as below.

```
<requestHandler class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true" name="search">
    <!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
         will be overridden by parameters in the request
      -->
     <lst name="defaults">
       <int name="rows">1000000</int>
     </lst>
 <!-- SearchHandler for CQL Solr queries:
    this handler doesn't support any additional components, only default parameters
    -->

  <requestHandler class="com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.handler.component.CqlSearchHandler" name="solr_query">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <int name="rows">1000000</int>
     </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

But still I am getting same issue. Please let me know what will be the solution for this. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it should be managed from the schema. The query has a `rows` and a `start` parameter. Use those: rows defines the max number of items to return, start defines the first item in the list to return:

```
q=isd:9*&rows=22&start=17&wt=json
```

`isd:9*` returns all items where isd starts with 9.

`start=17` says begin at the 18th item in the list.

`rows=22` returns 22 items, from 18 to 40.

Comment: I am using to retrieve the records by cqlsh . Then how can I get all records by cql command prompt side,

Comment: I'm not familiar with that syntax, but here are a few examples: https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchCql.html so you can play around with it and test it on your system. Let me know the final query version and I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: one more issue I am able to check now.. that if I am trying to search like this.. solr_query = 'num1:*1* OR num2:*1*';  It gives me records.. but If I am trying same syntax on text like chinese character, it is not working for me.. solr_query = 'col1:*金泽* OR col2:*金泽*';  this gives me 0 records....

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select id from empo where solr_query = 'isd:9*' limit 1300;
```

this will give you all 1300 rows, by default solr limits the rows it return to 10.

Comment: you won't want to do it this way, it's going to be dreadfully slow. you'll want to pass start and rows params into the solr query and page the results